# Как сделать чтобы блоки подгонялись под размеры родительного блока?

Tags: html, css, css3

Здравствуйте.

Мучаюсь уже давно, но очень надо!

Задача:

Есть 3 блока:

1 - блок (родитель) width:100%
2 - блок (вложен в первый) width: 100% margin:10px;
3 - блок (вложен во второй) width: 100% margin:10px;

Вопрос: **Как сделать так чтобы 2 и 3й блоки при изменении размера экрана сохраняли отступы 10px от родительного, а 3й от 2го?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<div class="parent bg-red">
    <div class="child bg-orange">
        <div class="subchild bg-yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .parent {
        height: 200px; /* для демонстрации */
        width: 100%;
    }
    /**
     * Не задавайте ширину. Она будет рассчитана автоматически.  
     * Блочные элементы по умолчанию занимают 100% ширины родителя.
     */
    .child, .subchild {
        margin: 10px;            
    }
    .parent, .child, .subchild {
        /* Вот тут вся магия. Этим правилом мы запрещаем схлопывание отступов */
        overflow: auto;
    }
    /* Далее все для демонстрации */
    .child {
        height: 150px;
    }
    .subchild {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .bg-red {
        background-color: #FF4136;
    }
    .bg-orange {
        background-color: #FF851B;
    }
    .bg-yellow {
        background-color: #FFDC00;
    }
</style>
```

Прочитайте статью "[Схлопывающиеся отступы](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy)", чтобы лучше понять, как это работает.

> Предположим, что в нижнем блоке располагается дочерний элемент, у
>   которого задан верхний отступ. Из блочной модели следует, что такой
>   отступ сдвигает дочерний элемент вниз относительно верхнего края
>   родителя. Однако с учётом схлопывающихся отступов результат будет
>   иным. Отступ словно выйдет за пределы блока и будет задавать
>   расстояние между верхним блоком и родительским элементом

Comment: отличное волшебство спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev я забыл сразу добавить `overflow: auto` к родительскому элементу. Сейчас это исправлено.

Comment: как вариант вместо margin можно использовать padding для элементов родителей.....